# Keep on getting " TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' " error code when my code is run. Can anyone identify my problem/

Tags: python

Code runs fine until the "for num in l:" part. As stated I receive a 
" TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' " error code at that part. I am trying to add all the numbers in the list together and to then print the answer. Can anyone spot what I have done wrong and/or recommend any changes to the code?

Have tried a few different methods (for eg. sum(l)) but all have given either the same error or a different one.

```
<!-- language: python -->
k = 1
l = []
ans1 = input("Please enter first number:   ")
l.append(ans1)
ans2 = input("Please enter seconde number:   ")
l.append(ans2)
yesno = input("Do you want to add more numbers to this list?:   ")
yesno = yesno.upper()
while yesno == "YES":
    ansmore = input("Please enter next number:   ")
    l.append(ansmore)
    yesno = input("Do you want to add more numbers to this list?:  ")
    yesno = yesno.upper()
    if (yesno == "NO"):
        break
#This is the problematic section
for num in l:
    k+=sum(l)
print(k)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you get from `input` is a `str` (string) by default. Therefore, you're trying to add 1 (the value of `k`, and an `int`) to all the strings in `l`.

You just need to cast the values you get from `input` to `int`:

```
k = 1
l = []

ans1 = input("Please enter first number:   ")
l.append(int(ans1))
ans2 = input("Please enter seconde number:   ")
l.append(int(ans2))
yesno = input("Do you want to add more numbers to this list?:   ")
yesno = yesno.upper()
while yesno == "YES":
    ansmore = input("Please enter next number:   ")
    l.append(int(ansmore))
    yesno = input("Do you want to add more numbers to this list?:  ")
    yesno = yesno.upper()
    if (yesno == "NO"):
        break

#This is the problematic section
for num in l:
    k+=sum(l)
print(k)
```

A few other things:

1. You could benefit from defining a function to take input, which will try to convert the input to `int`, and prompt the user to re-enter something otherwise.
2. I'm not sure why you set `k = 1` and then add `sum(l)` to it for every element in `l`; that will result in 1 + the length of `l` multiplied by its sum, which I'm not sure is what you want. If you just want the sum of all entered numbers, `k = sum(l)` will be enough, *wihout* a `for` loop.
3. You don't need both `while yesno == 'YES'` and `break` on `if yesno == 'NO'`. They test two different things: one stops looping once the user *enters anything that is not `'YES'`, and the other stops looping *once the user enters `'NO'`*.